# How is this "Answer" not just a restatement of the question?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25838747/921224) as "Not An Answer" but the flag got disputed.

As far as I can see, it is someone asking the same (or a very similar) question to the OP.

Despite this it seems to be the most upvoted response which is why I guess the flag got disputed.

### Edit

I misused the word *declined*, I apologise, my flag was **disputed**. Until today I simply assumed that any flag that didn't lead to an action was declined, something new every day eh!

Comment: OK... how did this non-answer get four upvotes?

Comment: Well, ["Me too!" containing additional details apparently _is_ an answer, so...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324340/why-does-the-help-center-seem-to-indicate-me-too-is-a-valid-answer)

Comment: This is a text-book NAA for me. I can't find a single piece of valuable information in this post, _as an answer_ (maybe it could make a good question), which differs from the post you linked @CodeCaster.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to the notice of the community. Feels like justice is served after all (downvotes)

Comment: Your flag was disputed, not declined. Your flag never even reached a moderator to begin with.

Comment: @BoltClock mind sharing a link that clears the difference between the two?

Comment: @CinCout: A NAA flag can be disputed by the review process, in which case both the flag and the review are marked resolved just as had the flag been marked helpful by a unanimous review. I'm not sure if a unanimous "Looks OK" review would mark a flag declined by the review process, but certainly not in this case, and in all of these cases the NAA flag never reaches the mod queue. It's only when a review is left unresolved for a set amount of time (I forget how long) that the flag is promoted to the mod queue.

Comment: @BoltClock I think the flag can be declined from the review queue also. [From this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue): *if the number of (Recommend)Delete reviews is >= the number of Looks Good reviews, mark flags "disputed" and raise DisputedLowQuality mod flag. Otherwise, mark flags "declined".* Which is weird, since there were 4 "Recommend Deletion" and 3 "Looks OK". Hmm...

Comment: I added a explaination of disputed vs declined flags to my answer @CinCout

Comment: @Tunaki: That's what I said. There's no way this flag could have been declined - it should have been disputed, and *was*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This definitely looks like a question to me. Not an answer, certainly.

What's curious with this one is that it [passed a LQP Review with 4x "Recommend Deletion" and 3x "Looks OK" 2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12610022)

What's even more incredible is that it has 4 upvotes.

So, I guess just ... reflag it? Flag for moderator attention? Maybe both?

**Update:** As a result of this meta post, the answer has accumulated -7 votes and has been deleted by 3 delete votes. So I guess this case is (semi) solved. [Link for 10k users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25838747/921224)

**Update 2:** [According to BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325904/how-is-this-answer-not-a-question#comment355763_325904) your flag was disputed, not declined. There is a very important distinction between these two. Declined flags usually are declined by moderators and having too many will limit your ability to flag more. Disputed flags just mean that the community review process came to a different conclusion than your flag. (Like what happened here, the LQP Review accumulated 3x Looks OK votes, thus completing the review without deleting the post)

Comment: I have downvoted and now flagged it as NAA. Let's see what the result is this time.

Comment: I have cast a delete vote. Hopefully others will do the same, just in case your NAA flag fails to reach the mod team *again*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It has accumulates -7 votes and 2 delete votes since this was posted, so I guess the community agrees that its indeed NAA

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ... And now deleted.

Comment: Strange on the voting front, perhaps one of the people voting to keep it had more weight behind their vote?

Comment: @Troyseph How many "recommend deletion" votes an A needs to be deleted is dependent on the score it has, which users review and a couple more things. [Here are the exact mechanics](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318744/how-does-the-lqrq-work) of that if you're interested in knowing more.

Comment: Who are these idiots thinking that answer "Looks Ok"?? ... what's the point of reviewing if you're going to do such a bad job, more importantly how are they not getting caught out for their poor performance? (Edit: wow 2 of them are ~20k)

Comment: I dont understand why so many no reason up-votes and down votes are given on this site.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: [This is why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285088/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have no problem when people state some improvement even if they don't tell that they down rated, but i hate people who just anonymously down rate.

Comment: @ritwiksinha A downvote is a message in and of itself. "This answer is not useful" or "This question does not show any research effort. It is unclear or not useful." Thats all you need to know. Downvotes are our main quality control tool and people are not obligated to follow up on them or explain.